# How to set native memory in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello I am facing following Error. What i have read by googling this is that I am running out of native memory. Any help in resolving this will be highly appreciated. Please note that i am using 32-bit Windows 7.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.start(JIoEndpoint.java:478)
```

Comment: is it a web app look at http://blog.egilh.com/2006/06/2811aspx.html

Comment: what are the memory configurations, like `-xmx`, `-xms` passed to the jvm

Comment: xmx 2560 -xms 1536... If there is any other configuration needed please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: It will not work as a 32-bit windows system can access only 2GB or RAM irrespective what you provide. And read the link I provided above

Comment: Thanks Arun. I have been through the link you provided.And i think i understand why this problem is occurring let me change some configurations and check. Thanks a lot for the link and support.

Answer (score 2):

You are running out of threads, which is not directly related to available memory.

There is an upper limit to the number of threads you can create in Java on a given platform (usually given by the operating system).

My guess would be that this message shows after a while and you have a servlet that does not finish correctly.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html

Look at the java -Xmx option; you may need to increase the heap size.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are running out memory which is limiting the number of threads then you can adjust the stack-space associated with each thread with the following JVM option.

```
-XX:ThreadStackSize=128k
```

The default stack size is 512k or 1024k (I think) depending on if you are running a 32 or 64-bit JVM.

If you are running out of the *number* of threads then you may need to create [`ExecutorService` thread-pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or other mechanisms to run many jobs on fewer threads.

Here's a good link for more information:  [What is the limit to the number of threads you can create?](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html)